# Error writing to connection: No space left on device

Tags: mysql, r, dbi

I'm using R to write a table in a MySQL database. I never had any issues with it before, but somehow this error just appeared:

```
Error in write.table(escape(value[from:to, , drop = FALSE]), file = conb,  : 
    Error writing to connection:  No space left on device
```

I double-checked and there's still a ton of space in the destination schema, so I'm not sure why this error still persists. My only guess is it's writing on some sort of temporary folder before writing on the destination schema, and that temp folder is full. How can I clear it?

Is there a different reason for the error? How can I resolve it?

Comment: I can't find `escape(.)` in the `RMySQL` or `DBI` packages. Please include the code (and non-base packages) you use to get this error.

Comment: `dbWriteTable(conn = con.dw, name = 'f_orders', value = get_query, append = row.names = F)`. Packages loaded are `RMySQL`, `odbc`, `DBI`, `dplyr`, `stringr`

Comment: I found that this happens when number of rows is about 2M or more. For 1M rows it works on my side